# How can I reorder a 128 bit vector using Intel intrinsics?

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I have a 128-bit vector of 4 floats that have been calculated, and I want to change the order of this vector like so:

```
Vector A before reordering
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+

Vector A after reordering
+---+---+---+---+
| b | a | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
```

As I said the vector has been calculated by earlier computations so no way to use `_mm_set_ps()`... Anyone have a clue on how can it be done?

Comment: Compiling `__m128 f(__m128 x){return _mm_setr_ps(x[1],x[0],x[2],x[3]);}` with gcc or clang and `-O3 -msse4` yields `shufps $225, %xmm0, %xmm0`, looks like a strong hint...

Comment: See https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ for a handy search tool, and other links in the [sse tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info), and also the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  If you find your code has too many shuffles, look at re-arranging your data structures, or how you vectorize a nested loop, to reduce the amount of shuffling if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [**`SHUFPS`** instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SHUFPS.html) (shuffle packed single-precision floats).
The corresponding intrinsic is [**`_mm_shuffle_ps`**](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_shuffle_ps&expand=4767,4767):

```
__m128 _mm_shuffle_ps(__m128 a, __m128 b, unsigned int imm8);
```

The third parameter, an 8-bit immediate, is the permutation. This indicates how you want the values to be shuffled. To create this readably, you'll want to use the `_MM_SHUFFLE` macro. Here's a helpful graphical description of how `_MM_SHUFFLE` works, taken from [some old Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d3eabky(v=vs.71).aspx):

[image]

Comment: Will a compiler recognize when the destination xmm register is the same as the first source xmm register (m3 == m1) so that it does an in place shuffle (with a single SHUFPS insruction) as opposed to using a temp xmm register?

Comment: I usually skip `_MM_SHUFFLE` and write it as base four and then convert to base 16.  1032 in base four becomes (1*4+0)*16 + (3*4+2) = 0x4E.

Comment: Why do you oppose `_MM_SHUFFLE`, @Zboson? I don't understand how 0x4E would ever be clearer than `_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0,3,2)`.